Crude Inrush Limiter Single Phase Induction Motor
Looking for feedback,
building a cost-efficient inrush current limiter to a 230 V 1.5 kW single phase induction motor, by using a timer relay (16 A rating) to shunt/bypass an initial 30 Ω power-resistor after 100 ms.
Chose 30 Ω to provide 7.6 A, i.e. greater than the nominal 6.52 A the motor would draw once running.
Now the R1C1 creates a lowpass filter, sits around 100 Hz, so shouldn't interfere with line frequency (plus centrifugal s1 switch kicks).
Anything I'm missing?

Notes: avoiding NTCs in case quick restarts are needed.

Welcome! What springs to mind would be power rating on the resistor as you mention quick restarts. More expensive but slightly better performance for quick restarts would be to measure the current instead of fixed time on the relay is the motor is already spinning to not waste time and burn power in R1.

Thanks! Great point - chose a 100W rated power resistor that supports a 25x power overload for <1s, 12x <2s, 5x <5s. The reason I was leaning towards timer as the units are quite economic COTS.  What would that type of switch be called, is there an integrated component that does that?

I'm not an automation engineer, but hopefully there is some current release relay available as COTS. If too expensive/obscure and time for a restart is not an important factor, you only need to determine the maximum amount of restarts and dimension R1 accordingly. For my own projects with soft-starts, I try to pick an incandescent bulb which all have PTC from the factory and gives me visual indication. A 150 W (230 V) bulb will have roughly 30 ohm cold resistance. Can't overload it either with 230 V supply

The resistor should probably be left in circuit rather than disconnected.  Not sure, but by the time you have this engineered, it might be cheaper to buy one from automation direct.

Depending on switch time you may well be right - was hoping to isolate additional power drain post start - even though it would be miniscule.

You may also use a constant current source. No moving parts. Q2 should be thermally coupled to M1.
In the circuit below, D1-D4 rectify the current so that a single DC current source M1 can be used to limit the current.

When the current through R1 is low, Q1 is off, M1's gate is pulled up to 15V via R5, and M1 is fully on.

When the current through R1 exceeds say 7A, Q1 turns on and controls M1's gate to limit the current. Thus, the motor never sees more than 7A of current. The circuit acts as an AC current limiter.

As M1 gets hot due to constant current mode dissipation, Q2's Vbe drops at ≈2mV per K. Eventually as the temperature rises, Q2 turns on, turning on Q1, and limiting current through M1 to keep the temperature roughly constant. This provides thermal protection for M1.



simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
If the losses on the rectifier D1..D4 are not acceptable, two mosfets can be used. Their body diodes act as rectifiers during current limit. When the current is not limited, they are both turned on continuously, presenting only their channel resistance to the circuit. They have very low losses then.

simulate this circuit
Overvoltage, temperature and transient protection devices are not shown.

Wow - if this is your crude solution, I want to see your OTT solution :) You raise a fair point though, I haven't actually explored current limiters. Will explore as an additional route and share back here.
